# Jquery event triggered twice, due to off page clicking?

Tags: jquery

I know there are a lot of queries around this, but my issue is slightly different.

I have a several input fields which are bound to using

```
$('body').on('blur', '#fielda, #fieldb, #fieldc, #fieldd', function(){
   alert ('hello')
});
```

If I click in `fielda` enter a value and click out I get ONE alert,

however if I click into `fielda` and then click on an another application not in my browser that triggers the first alert, I clear that and then get a new alert.

How do I stop that happening.
I've set up a simple **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzovaemw/1/)** to show this.

Thanks

Comment: For me (Latest release build of Chome on Windows) that doesn't fire twice, it simply keeps firing until you close the window.

Comment: you could interrupt any event using the focus event which is when you enter a field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `document.hasFocus()`

> The `Document.hasFocus()` method returns a `Boolean` value indicating
>   whether the document or any element inside the document has focus.
>   This method can be used to determine whether the active element in a
>   document has focus.

```js
$('body').on('blur', '#fielda', function() {
  if (document.hasFocus()) {
    alert('hello')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="fielda" />
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to help on this demo, I'll try it on my script and report back.

Comment: Thanks that has sorted it :)